# Multiple use of `getConnection()` in a single block and impact performance issues

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, blocks, performance

I found a module someone created and looked into the code. I found that this person was making a lot connection as such in a single block:

```
public function checkStoreExists($storeID){
    $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
    // some code
}
public function checkCategoryExists($categoryID){
    $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
    // some code
}
public function checkBrandExists($brandID){
    $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
    // some code
}
public function checkRangeExists($rangeID){
    $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
    // some code
}

public function checkProductExists($productID, $rangeID){
    $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
    // some code
}

public function checkProductOptionExists($productID, $rangeID, $productSku){
    $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
    // some code
}

public function GetNextProductIndex(){
    $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
    // some code
}

public function GetNextProductOptionIndex(){
    $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
    // some code
}
```

Will that have any impact on performance? Is this okey to leave or should I adjust this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify following way:

```
private $connection;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getConnection()
{
    if (!$this->connection) {
        $this->connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
    }

    return $this->connection;
}
```

now use following way:

```
$connection = $this->getConnection()
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. The way he done it above would have any impact on performane? Or any other down effects? Curiosity

Comment: Open vendor/magento/framework/App/ResourceConnection.php and check getConnection method then you understand the effect.

Answer (score 0):

No it will be not affect that much on performance & but it does in code readability & maintaining it.

As `getConnection` in core call `getConnectionByName`

which code code is checking first if `connections` array have existed key then it will return that `connection` so not much load goes in connection but still it will call every time `getConnectionName` and check `$this->connections` array so it will affect lil bit..

```
public function getConnectionByName($connectionName)
    {
        $processConnectionName = $this->getProcessConnectionName($connectionName);
        if (isset($this->connections[$processConnectionName])) {
            return $this->connections[$processConnectionName];
        }

        $connectionConfig = $this->deploymentConfig->get(
            ConfigOptionsListConstants::CONFIG_PATH_DB_CONNECTIONS . '/' . $connectionName
        );

        if ($connectionConfig) {
            $connection = $this->connectionFactory->create($connectionConfig);
        } else {
            throw new \DomainException('Connection "' . $connectionName . '" is not defined');
        }

        $this->connections[$processConnectionName] = $connection;
        return $connection;
    }
```